# Compile bug in Visual Studio's Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2013

I have been working with many MVC4 projects with Visual Studio 2013, but only this project has the problem: the view page suddenly cannot realize the namespace (merely visual bug):

[image]
[image]

If I build the project, it's normal again (the namespaces and classes DO exist). It can be run or debugged fine.

[image]

The problem is that it persists, after I build, if I type something in the cshtml file for a while, or close and re-open the file, it happens again, and I have to build the project again. It also make Auto Indent (Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D) has problem if I don't build first.

How can I fix this?

**FOUND THE PROBLEM:**
It's because my DataContext also has a class named WispLink, therefore it cannot determine whether WispLink was a namespace or a class. I renamed the namespace WispLink to WispLinkNamespace, and it's ok now. Anyway, weird that it can still compile and run correctly.

Comment: Uh I have had this before and its quite hard to get rid of because it can be multiple problems. Check your webconfig and make sure system.web.MVC is an included namespace.

Comment: try a ReBuild , or Clean , then Build

Comment: @ScottSelby Tried, before and just now, the problem still happens after some time.

Comment: @Anon Yes, there are MVC namespaces in my WebConfig.         
`<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />`

Comment: Try editing the csproj file in notepad and ensure the references are there also. 'System.Web' being of most importance here.  Also, is your intelesense broken in the view?

Comment: I've seen this before and a quick fix for me was to simply edit WispModel.cs and save and then Visual studio would recognize the namespace again.

Comment: @Anon I tried adding System.Web into my WebConfig, the problem isn't solved. No, the Intellisense still works fine in the view. So I can tell that it is just visual bug, but it's annoying, because it breaks my indent.

Comment: @Christopher.Cubells Tried, not solved. It seems the problem was with the namespace, not that class. I will edit to add the (fake) error message

Comment: Does it happen with a new project too? Make sure you select the same framework if you try it. It could be your installation has been broken by an installation of something else.

Comment: No, my other 3 MVC4 projects are ok, new project also doesn't have this problem. Maybe I should report this to Microsoft?

Comment: Found the problem, added into the question. Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Comment: @DatVM instead of editing your question, you can write down solution as an answer and mark it. that'll not be useful for you but new visitors.

Comment: @AhmetKakıcı Thank you, added the answer, will mark it 2 days later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

It's because my DataContext also has a class named WispLink, therefore it cannot determine whether WispLink was a namespace or a class. I renamed the namespace `WispLink` to `WispLinkNamespace`, and it's ok now.

Anyway, weird that it can still compile and run correctly.